# TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

this is my controller file from which im trying to upload an image to the mongoDB

```
const bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Resource = mongoose.model('Resource');
const upload = require('express-fileupload');
const path=require('path');

app.use(upload())
app.post('/fileupload',function(req,res){
        var resource = new Resource();
        console.log(req.files);

        var file=req.files.file;
        var filename=file.name;
        resource.name=filename;

        file.mv('./resourceFiles/'+filename);
        var fpath='./resourceFiles/'+filename;
        resource.filePath=fpath;
        resource.save((err)=>{
            if(!err){
                console.log("file record")
                res.redirect('ownerHome');
            }
            else{
                console.log("error during insertion:"+ err);
            }
        });
    })
```

It throws an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of null
>       at /Users/Nikhil/Documents/node/auction/Controllers/owner.js:73:28
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Nikhil/Documents/node/auction/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (/Users/Nikhil/Documents/node/auction/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/Users/Nikhil/Documents/node/auction/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/Nikhil/Documents/node/auction/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>       at /Users/Nikhil/Documents/node/auction/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (/Users/Nikhil/Documents/node/auction/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>       at next (/Users/Nikhil/Documents/node/auction/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>       at Busboy. (/Users/Nikhil/Documents/node/auction/node_modules/express-fileupload/lib/processMultipart.js:130:41)
>       at Busboy.emit (events.js:323:22)
>       at Busboy.emit (/Users/Nikhil/Documents/node/auction/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:37:33)
>       at /Users/Nikhil/Documents/node/auction/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:304:17
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)

Following is my fileupload.ejs file:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <br>Select file:<input type="file" name="file">
    <br><input type="submit" value="Upload">
  </form>
```

Comment: Your input name is `file` so you would need to access it via `req.files.file`, not `req.files.filetoupload`. There might be other issues but you might want to start there.

Comment: I changed that however console.log(req.files) still returns null and the error remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly the problem was but when i used the same code in server.js (entry file) instead of the controller the code worked seamlessly.